# Macro to remove carriage return following number with a colon

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to revise a macro that inserts a carriage return in a Word document before a number containing a colon (such as 04:32) so that it REMOVES a carriage return that FOLLOWS a number containing a colon. Example:

The macro should change this:
02:41

Speaker: Okay. Let's continue.

to this:

02:41
Speaker: Okay. Let's continue.

This is the macro I'm trying to revise to accomplish this:

```
Sub Insert_CR_Before_Number_With_Colon()
Dim ParagraphCount As Long, BlankLineCount As Long
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim rng As Range, Y As Long
Dim vbmFlags As VbMsgBoxStyle, vbmResult As VbMsgBoxResult, strMsg1 As String, strMsg2 As String

Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

If oDoc.Range.Characters.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox "This document contains no text.", vbCritical, "Text check"
    Exit Sub
End If

strMsg1 = "This macro will insert one carriage return row before every occurrence of up to 4 TEXT numbers that contain a colon." & vbCr & vbCr _
 & "The purpose of this macro is to make the active document easier to read but also to make it easier to apply outline or multilevel numbering (and styles) to it. It will look for and process only text numbers, not Word's outline or multilevel numbering." & vbCr & vbCr _
 & "If the document already contains Word's numbering, the spacing can then be easily controlled through the number style, and there will be no need for this macro." & vbCr & vbCr _
 & "Do you wish to proceed?"

vbmFlags = vbYesNo
vbmResult = MsgBox(strMsg1, vbmFlags, "Insert Carriage Return Before Number Containing a Colon")

Select Case vbmResult

Case vbNo
    Exit Sub
End Select

Set rng = oDoc.Range
ParagraphCount = oDoc.Paragraphs.Count

 With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "([0-9][0-9]:[0-9])"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p\1" ' "^p\1" inserts CR BEFORE the number
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

I thought I could change the

```
.Text = "([0-9][0-9]:[0-9])"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p\1" ' "^p\1" inserts CR BEFORE the number
```

statements to look for the number with a colon followed by a carriage return. I have tried various versions of adding ^p to the .Text statement, but nothing worked.

Comment: See item 9 at https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 0):

Pls try.

```vb
    .Text = "([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})^13"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 " ' replace ^p with a space
```

*Edit by OP:*
Thank you. I just realized I did not format the example properly. I actually wanted ONE carriage return after the number with the colon, not two or none, so that the number remains one line above the text. But I was able to modify your suggestion to accomplish this, as follows:

```
.Text = "([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})^13^13"
.Replacement.Text = "\1^13"
```